# Syntax highlighting shows a yellow bar on Windows 10

Tags: syntax-highlighting, microsoft-windows, colorscheme

Good afternoon,

I just started using the Ubuntu shell from Windows 10, and I copied my Mac `.vimrc` file. Everything seemed normal until these yellow bars started showing up at the end of some lines.
It doesn't seem to be search syntax highlighting. I used `:nohl` command but that doesn't seem to work.
It goes away if I manually highlight the lines and yank them, I would not like to do that every time I want to edit files.

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot of vim]

`.vimrc` file:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent

"autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
"autocmd FileType php setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
"autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4

set lbr
set tw=500
set ai
set si
set wrap
set t_Co=256
set number
set mouse=
"ar mousemodel=extend
"set clipboard=unnamedplus
set background=dark
syntax on
"let g:onedark_termcolors=16
set noshowmatch
map <F6> :next<CR>
map <F5> :previous<CR>
set formatoptions=r
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    Plug 'jwalton512/vim-blade'
    Plug 'maslaral/the-creator.vim'
    "Plug 'liuchengxu/space-vim-theme'
    Plug 'sainnhe/edge'
call plug#end()
"colorscheme space_vim_theme
"colorscheme the-creator
colorscheme edge
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of vim is installed in the Win/Ubuntu distro? (Or is it bring-your-own....?)

Comment: Dont set t_Co manually, please.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble . That may be overstating it. There are scenarios where it's desirable or even necessary to set `t_Co`. Some examples are in vim's documentation. Setting it globally, otoh, is not kosher. It should be inside a system-level conditional block or the like.

Comment: @BLayer `vim --version` says 8.0

Comment: If you're still having this issue... Can you check whether using `:set t_ut=` with an empty value like that solves it for you? See also: https://superuser.com/q/1526515/879179

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25533/18609